# Worst conversion sequence in list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, overloading, c++14

I don't understand how worst conversion sequences for initializer_list are ranked during overload resolution. For example:

```
#include <initializer_list>

void fnc (std::initializer_list<int>){}
void fnc (std::initializer_list<long>){}

struct CL1 {
    operator short(){return 1;} };

struct CL2 {
    operator short(){return 1;} };

int main() {
    CL1 cl1;
    CL2 cl2;
    fnc ({cl1, cl2});
}
```

Here is a call of overloaded fnc function and overload resolution finds the best-viable function. The candidates are 2 functions which are ranked by comparing their needed conversion sequences.

The Standard (n4296) 13.3.3.1.5/4 [over.ics.list] says:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is std::initializer_list and all the
>   elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to X, the
>   implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to
>   convert an element of the list to X

For `std::initializer_list<int>` both conversions (CL1 -> int, CL2 -> int) are indistinguishable and both can be worst conversion (user-defined conversion + promotion). Simularly for `std::initializer_list<long>`, but with worst conversion sequence as user-defined conversion + standard conversion. And then the main question: which conversion (for cl1 or cl2) is selected as worst? Assume that in both initializer lists the worst conversion is selected as first (for cl1). Then, according to 13.3.3.2/3.3 [over.ics.rank]

> User-defined conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence
>   than another user-defined conversion sequence U2 if they contain the
>   same user-defined conversion function or constructor or they
>   initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either
>   case the second standard conversion sequence of U1 is better than the
>   second standard conversion sequence of U2.

the case with int is better because its second standard conversion sequence is better (promotion against standard conversion) and both conversions contain the same operator short(). Then assume that for `std::initializer_list<long>` worst conversion is for second element (cl2), and here is ambuguity because conversion functions are different.

Comment: On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/189a852378f2d4c0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Columbo, I don't understand how worst conversion sequences for initializer_list are ranked during overload resolution, because the result of that resolution may be different depending on whether or not user-defined conversion function in those sequences is same (that difference may be according to 13.3.3.2/3.3 [over.ics.rank], which is mentioned in my question above)

Comment: @user3514538 it appears to me that you found a defect here. The closest to apply would be "If several different sequences of conversions exist that each convert the argument to the parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence associated with the parameter is defined to be the unique conversion sequence designated the ambiguous conversion sequence.", it seems. But that's totally unintended and should not apply because a call using the ambiguous conversion sequence is illformed.

Comment: Although it should not matter much what of the two conversion sequences are used to represent the list initialization. The matter that counts is that it's a user defined conversion with a given second standard conversion sequence. What conversion function is taken is not important for the representation of the list initialization sequence at large (only important for the individual elements). However formally I think you have a point and I recommend posting to std-discussion as a defect report. Also in light that GCC and Clang disagree about the result.